# PHP: Check if variable is type of string AND is not empty string?

Tags: php, performance, micro-optimization

I need to check if the passed variable is type of string, and it is not empty. I have the following function:

```
function isNonEmptyStr($var)
{
    if(isset($var)) {
        if(is_string($var)) {
            if(strlen($var) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

results I expect:

```
echo(isNonEmptyStr(''));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(' '));// true
echo(isNonEmptyStr('a'));// true
echo(isNonEmptyStr('1'));// true
echo(isNonEmptyStr(1));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(0));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(0.0));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(0.1));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(array()));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(new myObj()));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(true));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(false));// false
echo(isNonEmptyStr(null));// false
```

The function works fine.

My question: Is there a way to improve function performance without effecting the results?

I'm talking about "micro optimization" (I use this function very heavily).

**EDIT**:

For those who are asking:

```
echo(isNonEmptyStr(0));// should return false, because it's not a string
echo(isNonEmptyStr(1));// should return false, because it's not a string
echo(isNonEmptyStr('0'));// should return true, because it's a non-empty string
echo(isNonEmptyStr('1'));// should return true, because it's a non-empty string
```

**Note:** a non-empty string = a string which if tested with strlen() function it would return > 0

Comment: You can get rid if `isset()` since it is alway set by your function definition

Comment: Could just use `!empty($var)` if you already know its a string.

Comment: If you use this for get and post vars they will always be strings.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more suited for code review?

Comment: @JohnConde - Actually, If you send in NULL, `isset()` will fail. But that's still irrelevant for this question. :)

Comment: Should  "1" be processed as a string or a integer in string quotes?

Comment: Amazeballs how many people [do not understand `empty`](http://kunststube.net/isset) in this thread...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a simple little benchmarking script you can modify to see what works best.  I just tried a few variations of the same thing, the first one is the fastest by a small margin, but they are basically all the same.  And there isn't really a simpler way for you to write it.

Also `$val === ''` is slightly faster than `empty($val)`, on top of being more strictly correct for you.

Additionally, since this is basically a one liner, why not just cut the overhead of making it a function and call `is_string($val) && $val !== ''` directly.  It don't make a huge difference, but its noticeable for millions of iterations, but I doubt this procedure will be the main bottleneck in any of your code ever...

```
function is_non_empty_string_1($val)
{
    return is_string($val) && $val !== '';
}

function is_non_empty_string_2($val)
{
    return gettype($val) === 'string' && $val !== '';
}

function is_non_empty_string_3($val)
{
    switch (true) {
        case !is_string($val): return false;
        case $val === '': return false;
    }

    return true;
}

$values = array('', '1', new stdClass(), 1, 2, 3, 999, array(), array());
$runs = 2000000;


function benchmark($test, $values, $runs, $func)
{
    $time = time();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $runs; $i++) {
        foreach ($values as $v) {
            $func($v);
        }
    }
    echo $test . '. ' . (time() - $time) . PHP_EOL;
}

benchmark(1, $values, $runs, 'is_non_empty_string_1');
benchmark(2, $values, $runs, 'is_non_empty_string_2');
benchmark(3, $values, $runs, 'is_non_empty_string_3');
```

Results:

```
1. 5
2. 6
3. 6
```

Comment: @deceze thanks for your effort and explanation. So far, the fastest function is_non_empty_string_1($val) by Flosculus, although the difference between this function and yours is very tiny

Comment: FWIW: Missing what I've seen often for empty string,  `strlen > 0` instead of `!== ''`.

Answer (score 6):

1. You should not need to call `isset` inside a function, since you're testing a variable which is defined in the function signature. If you do not pass a value into the function PHP will trigger notices, which should take care of the problem.
2. You can inline the entire thing:

   ```
   function isNonEmptyStr($var) {
       return is_string($var) && strlen($var) > 0;
   }
   ```

   This might be a tiny bit more performant or not, but mostly is reads a lot more sensibly.

Apart from these points, there's not a lot more to simplify. If you want to do exactly this check of *is string and is not empty*, then this is the check to do. If you're saying you're using this *a lot*, perhaps you need to either embrace the dynamically typed nature of PHP and type juggling more (requires you to know exactly when what might be cast to what though), or you need to have fewer ingress points for your data where you do validation and can rely more on your done validation throughout your app.

Comment: This fails if $var is an array? Or I am missing something?

Comment: @Mirko Define "fails"…!?

Comment: @Mirko - an array will return false at `is_string`. The function correctly rejects arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the passed variable is type of string use the function `is_string($var)`. See the example below:

```
<?php
    var_dump( is_string('hello') ); // true
    var_dump( is_string('') ); // true
    var_dump( is_string('5') ); // true
    var_dump( is_string('false') ); // true
?>
```

and to check if it is not empty, you can use the function `isset()` See the example below:

```
<?php
    $str = '';
 
    var_dump(isset($str)); // true
?>
```

Read more in :
[How to check if a variable is a String in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-string-in-php/)

[How to check if a variable is undefined in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-undefined-in-php/)

Answer (score -1):

```
function isNonEmptyString($var){
    return !empty($var) && is_string($var);
}
```

If you check !empty before it will avoid checking is_string if the string is already empty this will avoid 1 check.

Comment: And if he checks `is_string()` first and it isn't a string, he can avoid 1 check. :)

Comment: `'0'` is considered `empty`.

Comment: @deceze the function should return true if '0' was passed

Comment: @evilReiko And it doesn't do that, now does it!?

Comment: This function is by far, the fastest valid one, it's almost x3 faster than the original! It's pretty strange and awesome that if is_string() is placed before !empty() the function goes a noticeably slower!

Comment: @evilReiko But this `isNonEmptyString('0')` **returns `false`**, against your specification!

Comment: @deceze oh wait you are right, this function returns false against '0' !

Comment: @evilReiko Got a little tied up there in double-negatives, ey? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$var = ' ';

if(!empty($var) && is_string($var)) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: `'0'` is considered `empty`.

Comment: You're right, your problem is actually much worse. You're letting any *non empty value* pass! `new stdClass` will also qualify as an "non empty string" according to this code.